# updating mysqli data using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form which retrieves various values from my database and displays it in a form. The form contains text boxes, radio, drop down menus. The retrieving part works perfectly and the correct values are displayed for each field. But then when I want to change the field and update the data, it's not updating. Can some please help me with this. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_dealer_info ";
    $sql .= "SET phone = '$phone', email = '$email', sfid = '$sfid', ... WHERE id = '$idhidden' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!$result){
        die('Could not update data: '. mysqli_error());
    }
    else{
        echo "Updated Successfully";
    }
}
<input type = "hidden" name = "idhidden" id = "idhidden" value = "" /> // My hidden input to store the id
```

It displays "Updated Successfully" but isn't actually updating.

Comment: Parameterize your query. Do you have a `where` clause?

Comment: Even if you run the update, doesn't mean any rows were affected. What is `mysqli_affected_rows($conn)`?

Comment: I forgot to include the where clause but I do have it. i have updated my query above. Still nothing though

Comment: mysqli_affected_rows($conn) is 0 !

Comment: Output the query and execute on your DB, does it work there? Perhaps there are just no rows to update based on the `where`?

Comment: So i created a hidden input tag and am storing the row id in that. Then using that id in the WHERE clause

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by output the query? Like echo it? I'm kinda new to this so not really sure

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005). I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a function for](http://paragoncds.com/grumpy/pdoquery/#function) to make it extremely easy, clean, and more secure than using non-parameterized queries. Also, [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) may help you choose between `MySQLi` and `PDO`

Comment: If you mean on phpmyadmin then it works over there

Comment: why do you have a ... before your where clause?

Comment: ```$sql .= "SET phone = '$phone', email = '$email', sfid = '$sfid', WHERE id = '$idhidden' "; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);``` try that as you where clause

Comment: This is the error I'm getting. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = ''' at line 1"

Comment: I have a ... before where clause because I have about 20 columns and didn't feel like typing them all here, but they are similar to the ones shown above

Comment: Is `$idhidden` retrieved from `$_POST['idhidden']`? Because if not, your `where` would be trying to find a blank id

Comment: Yeah I created the variable like this 
$idhidden = $_POST['idhidden'] ?? ' ' ;

Answer (score -1):

you are missing where condition and `';'` in the sql statement

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_dealer_info ";
$sql .= "SET phone = '$phone', email = '$email', sfid = '$sfid' WHERE #here where condition #here ";
```

Comment: Updated my query above to include the WHERE clause but it still doesn't update

Comment: UPDATE Syntax
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;

Comment: So I need to have 2 semicolons in that line?

Comment: need another eg? with php

Comment: "..." are the values for all the columns I have. But I tried with 2 semicolons and still nothing

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}                check if result also returns true

Comment: `;` is not required. A `where` also is not required.

Comment: sorry for that mistake leave as it is

Comment: And like I said in a comment above, mysqli_affected_rows($conn) is giving me 0. So what exactly would that mean?

Comment: try it mysql statement in examples of w3 schools https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_update_2

Comment: some times it happens in my system too . i will change to objecj oriented  try nested if else statement check connection

Comment: use prepare and execute statements

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_dealer_info SET phone = '".$phone."', email = '".$email."', sfid = '".$sfid."', ... WHERE id = ".$idhidden; 
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if(!$result){ 
        die('Could not update data: '.  mysqli_error()); 
     } else{ 
        echo "Updated Successfully";
    } 
 }
```

Comment: The update only works if in my where clause, I have the account name instead of the id. Whenever I put id, it doesn't work. Can someone please please help with what the issue is?